# How can I remove or hide delete button in kanban view?

Tags: xml, view, odoo, odoo-10, kanban

How can I remove or hide the delete button in the Kanban view?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make delete false in views level put
where you define the view

Comment: <kanban delete="0">